# Generating apk by command "flutter build apk" in vs code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I want to generate apk in vs code by command `flutter build apk`, So :

1. I install Android Studio and Android SDK in path `C:\Android_SDK`.
2. I execute command `flutter config --android-sdk "c:\Android_SDK"` in vscode terminal
3. I Restart vscode.
4. I defined enviroment variable `ANDROID_HOME` with value `C:\Android_SDK`.
5. I execute command `flutter build apk` in terminal.
   but returns this error :

> Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 33 in
> c:\Android_SDK\licenses License for package Android SDK Platform 33
> accepted. Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision 3)".
> "Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision 3)" ready. Installing
> Android SDK Platform 33 in c:\Android_SDK\platforms\android-33
> "Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision 3)" complete. "Install
> Android SDK Platform 33 (revision 3)" finished. Font asset
> "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1645184
> to 2356 bytes (99.9% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by
> providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
> ERROR: Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the
> missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in
> D:\Projects\zTemp\MehChat_Frontend\build\app\outputs\mapping\release\missing_rules.txt.
> ERROR: R8: Missing class
> com.google.errorprone.annotations.CanIgnoreReturnValue (referenced
> from: com.google.crypto.tink.KeysetManager
> com.google.crypto.tink.KeysetManager.add(com.google.crypto.tink.KeyTemplate)
> and 52 other contexts) Missing class
> com.google.errorprone.annotations.CheckReturnValue (referenced from:
> com.google.crypto.tink.InsecureSecretKeyAccess and 1 other context)
> Missing class com.google.errorprone.annotations.Immutable (referenced
> from: com.google.crypto.tink.InsecureSecretKeyAccess and 40 other
> contexts) Missing class
> com.google.errorprone.annotations.RestrictedApi (referenced from:
> com.google.crypto.tink.aead.AesEaxKey$Builder
> com.google.crypto.tink.aead.AesEaxKey.builder() and 6 other contexts)
> Missing class javax.annotation.Nullable (referenced from:
> java.lang.Object
> com.google.crypto.tink.PrimitiveSet$Entry.fullPrimitive and 86 other
> contexts)
>
> > Compilation failed to complete
>
> - Try:
>
> > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> > Run with --scan to get full insights.
> > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
>
> BUILD FAILED in 16m 19s Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
> 981.2s Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

There is solution for this problem?

Comment: what operating system are you using? add photo of your environment variable.

Comment: mr @AmirHossein , my operating system is `windows 11`.

Comment: Add photo of your Android SDK release 26 to see it's content

Comment: mr @AmirHossein , photo of my Android SDK release 26 's content uploaded. i downloaded from [https://soft98.ir/mobile/13883-android-sdk.html](https://soft98.ir/mobile/13883-android-sdk.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just type this in your terminal:

```
flutter config --android-sdk path of your sdk
```

For example:

```
flutter config --android-sdk c:\android\sdk
```

Let me know if your problem solved or not

**Happy Coding :)**

Comment: thanks @AmirHossein;
vscode terminal output, after execute top command :

`PS D:\Projects\zTemp\MehChat_Frontend> flutter config --android-sdk D:\Android.SDK.Release.26.1.1.Win\tools
Setting "android-sdk" value to "D:\Android.SDK.Release.26.1.1.Win\tools".

You may need to restart any open editors for them to read new settings.
PS D:\Projects\zTemp\MehChat_Frontend> flutter build apk
[!] No Android SDK found. Try setting the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
PS D:\Projects\zTemp\MehChat_Frontend> `

notice : i restarted vs code 2 more.

Comment: Download sdk from another website or install android studio and let it download automatically

Comment: The result of the last actions was placed in the text of the question.